# ffmpeg – adding closed captions CEA-708

Tags: video, ffmpeg, closed-captions, srt

I am trying to embed closed captioning into my .mp4. I already have an .srt file with my subtitles and timing and have been trying iterations of the following:

> ffmpeg -i [source file].mp4 -i [source file].srt -c:v copy -c:a copy
>   -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng [output file].mp4

This does provide me with an .mp4 that has optional subtitles when playing in QuickTime and VLC, but when I play the file on a television and push the CC button on the remote, it says there is no closed captioning available.

I am totally new to closed captions and really have no idea about pretty much any of it. Any help would be very greatly appreciated please!

Thanks

Comment: There are many different caption formats. mov_text is not 708. Ffmpeg, I believe, does not have a 608/708 encoder. There is an open source project I made named libcaption (google it) that I made that may be what you are looking for.